# Переменные доступные сервису, активити и фрагментам

Tags: android

**Дано:**

- несколько активити
- несколько фрагментов
- сервис получения координат

Когда координаты получены - их надо куда-то сохранить, чтобы они потом были доступны для сервиса и если пользователь откроет приложение - для активити тоже.
И при получении новых координат - обновлять их в этих переменных.

Как лучше всего это сделать ?

Я смотрю в сторону SharedPreference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharedPreference будет лучше всего т.к.:

1. Не зависит от того, откуда вы получаете/записываете данные (сервис/активити/фрагмент)
2. Записываются они синхронно и не получится так, что в одном месте старые данные, а в другом новые.
3. В отличие от статических переменных к-л класса нет вероятности выгрузки класса из JVM

Comment: Спасибо, Юрий) По поводуSharedPreference  мне интересен такой еще вопрос: на сколько быстро туда записывается переменная ? Т.е. Если я ее записал и буквально сразу же мне ее надо использовать.

Comment: @researcher, вроде, если я правильно понял то что читал на сей счёт, доступ к этим данным идёт по очереди и запись/получение данных идёт в порядке вызова этих операций. Т.е. если вы начали что-то писать туда, то не сможете прочитать что-либо пока запись не будет завершена.

Comment: Спасибо. Почитаю по этому поводу.